# Getting one Activity from another within If case condition

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to insert data using the Retrofit library. The data has been inserted successfully and I am also receiving the response from the API, but my error is that I am not getting the intent Activity (`AdminActivity.class`) after the `Toast`. Can anyone help me on this??

```
private void createUserResponse() {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        CreateUserRequest createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest(editTextUserId.getText().toString().trim(),
                editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim(),
                editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim(),
               editTextProfileImage.getText().toString().trim(), editTextSchoolId.getText().toString().trim(),editTextRole.getText().toString().trim());

        Call<CreateUserResponse> createUserResponseCall = apiInterface. createUserCall(createUserRequest);

        createUserResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<CreateUserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CreateUserResponse> call, Response<CreateUserResponse> response) {
                Log.d("CreateUser" , "onResponse: " + response.body().getMessage());
                String status = response.body().getStatus();
                if (status.equals("sucess")){
                    String message = response.body().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"User Created Successfully" + message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), AdminActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else{
                    String message = response.body().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CreateUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

 }
```

Comment: Can you share your error log?

Comment: @Suresh Kumar show your error logcat

Comment: Not receiving any errors but not getting the AdminActivity.class inside the if condition does I need to do anything

Comment: What does the Toast say?? i want to know it?

Comment: Toast is User created successfully! which is returning from API @Xenolion

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo within your `if-else` condition, so your code do not execute the `if` statement even if you get a successful response.

Fix the following typo and try again:

```
 if (status.equals("success")) // fixed typo on "sucess" word
```